# get multiple return value in stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MobileDevice]
@platesourcecnt integer,
@plateCategory integer
as
begin
declare @SplateSourcecount integer,
@SplateCategory integer,
@Splatecode integer


select @SplateSourcecount= count(ps.PSID)from PlateSource_tbl ps 
if @SplateSourcecount <> @platesourcecnt
begin
select PSID,PS from  PlateSource_tbl where Deleted=0
end
else
 begin
return 1 

end

Select @SplateCategory=COUNT(pcat.PCID) from PlateCategory_tbl pcat
if @SplateCategory <> @plateCategory
 begin
select PCID,PC,PSID from  PlateCategory_tbl where Deleted=0
end
else
begin 
return 2
end
```

end

Here my `platesource_tbl` `count` is `13`, if I pass value to `@platesourcecnt =13` then I am getting return value `1` but that time my second select query is not working.
If I pass other parameter than `13` to `@platesourcecnt` then getting both working.
What is wrong with my stored procedure?
Can I get  multiple return value in one stored procedure?

Comment: Why you want to return , u require it for?

Comment: i want to check wethar first query returned value or not?

Comment: then use the variable solution i have given below

Comment: yes,i used,now i am getting expected out put.

Comment: i can optimize this stored procedure better than this methode?

Comment: find the optimized proc below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot return two times , one return will take you out,

Instead use Select 1 for return 1 , Select 2 for return 2

Or Declare two variables @return1, @return2
At the end of Proc Select @return1 'return1',@return2 'return2'

Answer (score 0):

Try thiss Proc

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MobileDevice]
@platesourcecnt integer,
@plateCategory integer
as

if (select count(ps.PSID)from PlateSource_tbl ps )<> @platesourcecnt
select PSID,PS from  PlateSource_tbl where Deleted=0
else
raiserror('1st return',16,1)  

if (Select COUNT(pcat.PCID) from PlateCategory_tbl pcat)<> @plateCategory
select PCID,PC,PSID from  PlateCategory_tbl where Deleted=0
else
raiserror('2nd return',16,1)
```

Comment: Jst to know whether if statement returned values or not

Comment: U can but this is like a message which is helpful for you as you said that you want to know whether it is returning rows in first and second if statements.